# How to add dates within a range

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert a range of dates into a table, along with corresponding column data. My table's earliest date stops at 2017-3-16, but I need to add dates going back to 2016-1-1. See screenshot below for reference:

[image]

I'm sure I can figure out how to attribute day of the week, type of day, etc. using functions such as datepart, datename, etc. What I'm not certain of is how to insert a range of dates, between 2016-1-1 and 2017-3-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep this snippet handy as it is often needed. Simply set the high and low date variables and join your date on the CalendarDate field. If date gaps are ok then INNER JOIN, otherwise LEFT JOIN.

```
  DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2015' 
  DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '12/01/2016' 

;WITH OrderedDays as 
( 
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM OrderedDays WHERE DATEADD (DAY, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
),
Calendar AS
(
    SELECT
        DayIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CalendarDate),
        CalendarDate,
        CalenderDayOfMonth = DATEPART(DAY, CalendarDate),
        CalenderMonthOfYear = DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate),
        CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate),
        CalenderWeekOfYear = DATEPART(WEEK, CalendarDate),
        CalenderQuarterOfYear = DATEPART(QUARTER, CalendarDate),
        CalenderDayOfYear =  DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, CalendarDate),
        CalenderDayOfWeek =  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CalendarDate),
        CalenderWeekday =  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CalendarDate)   
    FROM
        OrderedDays                 
)
SELECT * FROM Calendar
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is going in my archive of nifty queries. Only other thing I need is the ability to insert the calendar key (MIN value currently 17241) and I need these new values to work backwards from that number. Other than that, I see how I can easily manipulate this query to do precisely what I need!

Comment: Use `datediff()` to compute calendar keys.